# Watch yourself (negative or positive)

Tags: meaning

Is "watch yourself" eventhough it means be careful, used more in nagative situations or nagatively? So, if someone says that to a child, the person is more about criticing the child than caring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Watch yourself" has a more negative air about it. It isn't something that I would use kindly. It has a connotation of almost sassiness, and so could even be considered rude in some contexts.

A kinder way of saying something similar to a child would be "Watch that you don't get hurt!" or "Take care."

Answer (score -1):

It is a warning that you have stepped over the line the next response if you continue will be much more forceful.